# Laravel Migrations - already a table with name "migrations"

Tags: laravel, laravel-migrations

I have a problem with Laravel (5.1.x) and Migrations. I am running it on an windows server with an integrated service account - so dont the application pool runs as the same account as the database.

Do get the correct scheme of my database, ill changed in the database.php file the name for the migrations table to:

```
'migrations' => 'dbo.migrations',
```

Because otherwise it will use my Scheme (because the command line runs as my account)

But when ill use that and run

```
php artisan migrate
```

It works only the first time, when i run it again, i tells me that there is already a migrations table in my database.

When ill use with:

```
'migrations' => 'migrations',
```

And the schema is now **username.migrations** it works when ill run the commands with my user.

It looks like that laravel is checking anywhere else if the migrations table exists, and try to create it again.

How can ill use the global database scheme with migrations (ill use that for every other tables too, and here it works fine as expected)

Any Ideas? Thanks in advance.